# C# and XSLT rounding difference

Tags: c#, xslt, rounding

I have got a weird difference between when rounding in XSLT and when rounding in C#.

```
<xsl:value-of select="round(325 div 50) * 50" />
```

gives me 350

But doing this in C#

```
Math.Round(325 / 50) * 50
```

gives me 300!

Any ideas how can I make the C# version behave the same as the XSLT version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.Round` rounds to the nearest **even** value as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx .

> The integer nearest a. If the fractional component of a is halfway
>   between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, then the
>   even number is returned.

This is known as **Banker's Rounding**.

If that is not the behaviour you expect, you can specify how you want rounding to occur as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8(v=vs.110).aspx .

```
Math.Round((double)325 / 50, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 50
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and thanks for explanation and links.

Comment: I think this explanation misses a part of the OP's problem, which is that he's doing an integer division.  `Math.Round(349 / 50) * 50` would also have given `300`.

Comment: `Math.Round(349 / 50) * 50` doesn't actually compile (try it and see @MarkDickinson)  - which is why I altered it to include the double cast in my answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That makes sense. (Presumably it doesn't compile because it doesn't know whether to use the `Double` overload or the `Decimal` overload?)